# Call to a member function where() on a non-object ? Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, where-clause, relational

i'm trying to retrieve the matching values from 2 tables, in order to make an user record.

My code:

```
$states = ['1','2'];
$cities = DB::table('cities')->get();
$state = $faker->randomElement($states);
$city= $faker->randomElement($cities->where('state_id',$state)->value('id'));
```

Current response:

"Call to a member function where() on a non-object".

Edit 1. Translated to english for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like the following:

```
$states = ['1','2'];
$state = $faker->randomElement($states);
$cities = DB::table('cities')->where('state_id', $state)->lists('id')->all();
$city = $faker->randomElement($cities);
```

Comment: it works! now gives the error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" but at least i can work with that, thank you !

Comment: Please try the last line as `$city = City::find($faker->randomElement($cities));`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$comuna = $faker->randomElement($comunas->where('region_id',$region[0])->where('region_id',$region[1])->get();
```

Comment: still gives error "Call to a member function where() on a non-object", i dont know why, i'm obviusly using an array :/